# java generic parameterized type

Tags: java, generics

Sorry for this simple question

In this class

```
class GenericTest{
    static <T> List<T> getList(List<T> list){
        return list;
    }
}
```

why this this  `<T>`  just after static needed in the declaration. I thought the return type `List<T`> is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are declaring that this method has a type parameter "T". If you didn't declare it then there is no way for the compiler to know what type you're talking about (T is not declared anywhere else).

Comment: Sjr is absolutely right. But it's worth pointing out there are two ways you can use generic in Java. You can have generic methods and generic classes. The above is an example of a generic method.